# python subprocess multiple commands with win path

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm trying to trigger the execution of a python script via conda.

I would then capture the output and report it to command prompt where this is executed.

This is basically the concept in the easiest way

wrap.py - wrapper inted to execute multiple times the following script

```
import subprocess
def wrap():
    while True:
        cmd1=r"call C:\\Users\\my_user\\anaconda3\\Scripts\\activate.bat"
        cmd2=r"cd C:\\myfolder\\mysubfolder"
        cmd3=r"C:\\Users\\my_user\\anaconda3\\python.exe C:\\myfolder\\mysubfolder\\test.py"
        proc = subprocess.run([cmd1,cmd2,cmd3])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    wrap()
```

test.py - script that has to be executed

```
def mytest():
   print("success")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mytest()
```

since mytest prints success once, I would like the output of the wrapper (run on anaconda) to be

```
(base) C:\myfolder\mysubfolder> python wrap.py
success
success
success
...
```

I tried with

1 - subprocess.Popen

2 - using shell=True or not

3 - using a list ["first command","second command","third command"] or a single string "first;second;third"

4 - using or removing "r" in front of the string, here the blanks are breaking the game

5 - using single or double ""

6- in my_user the underscore is also resulting in an encoding error

I actually tried to replicate at least 20 different stackoverflow "solutions" but none of them really worked for me. I also read properly the subprocessing page of python documentation, but this didn't help.

Any hint is appreciated, I'm lost.

Comment: You misunderstand what a subprocess does. It runs, then returns everything to the way it was before the subprocess ran.

For your immediate problem, probably simply figure out how to run a script inside an Anaconda environment without separately activating it. (I know how to do this with `virtualenv`, but can't help with Anaconda.)  Or even better, just `import` the Python code and run it in the current script if you can.

Comment: @tripleee thanks for your comment. it's important to me to execute it in a new instance everytime. the reason why I'm not porting everything there is because I'm using a component to take screenshot that is well known to run out of resources after a certain amount of run, in my case about 35. Therefore since I didn't find any suitable way to clean up the environment (I gave a try to different methods) the easiest way for me to handle the situation would be to just initiate the process from scratch everytime.

Comment: The duplicate explains how to do that - obviously the accepted answer has some flaws, but the other answers there should get you going. Please accept the duplicate and upvote whichever answer there lets you resolve your issue; this helps future visitors find the right resources, too. Thanks!

Comment: @tripleee basically I don't want to reuse one env - I want to create a new conda session everytime. And actually that works properly. My code get stuck on multiple commands execution.

Comment: The encoding error seems inexplicable. Without `r'...'` the backslashes could be problematic, but the underscore should be fine, unless you somehow managed to paste in some weird non-Unicode underscore character.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `subprocess.run([cmd1, cmd2, cmd3])` means run `cmd1` with `cmd2` and `cmd3` as command-line arguments to `cmd1`.  You instead want to execute a single sequence of shell commands; several of the things you are trying to do here require the shell, so you do want `shell=True`, which dictates the use of a single string as input, rather than a list consisting of a command and its arguments.

(Windows has some finicky processing behind the scenes which makes it not completely impossible to use a list of strings as the first argument with `shell=True`; but this really isn't portable or obvious. Just don't.)

Regarding the requirement for `shell=True` here, commands like `call` and `cd` (and `source` or `.` in Bourne-family shells) are shell built-ins which do not exist as separate binaries; if you don't have `shell=True` you will simply get "command not found" or your local equivalent. (Under other circumstances, you should generally [avoid `shell=True` when you can.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) But this is not one of those cases; here, it really is unavoidable without major code changes.)

If your shell is `cmd` I guess the command might look like

```py
subprocess.run(
    r"call C:\Users\my_user\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat & C:\Users\my_user\anaconda3\python.exe C:\myfolder\mysubfolder\test.py",
    shell=True)
```

or equivalently the same without `r` before the string and with all backslashes doubled; the only difference between an `r"..."` string and a regular `"..."` string is how the former allows you to put in literal backslashes, whereas the latter requires you to escape them; in the former case, *everything* in the string is literal, whereas in the latter case, you can use symbolic notations like `\n` for a newline character, `\t` for tab, etc.

In Python, it doesn't really matter whether you use single or double quotes; you can switch between them freely, obviously as long as you use the same opening and closing quotes.  If you need literal single quotes in the string, use double quotes so you don't have to backslash-escape the literal quote, and vice versa. There's also the triple-quoted string which accepts either quoting character, but is allowed to span multiple lines, i.e. contain literal newlines without quoting them.

If your preferred shell is `sh` or `bash`, the same syntax would look like

```py
subprocess.run(r"""
    source C:\Users\my_user\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat &&
    C:\Users\my_user\anaconda3\python.exe C:\myfolder\mysubfolder\test.py""",
    shell=True)
```

I left out the `cd` in both cases because nothing in your code seems to require the subprocess to run in a particular directory.  If you do actually have that requirement, you can add `cwd=r'C:\myfolder\mysubfolder'` after `shell=True` to run the entire subprocess in a separate directory.

There are situations where the facilities of `subprocess.run()` are insufficient, and you need to drop down to bare `subprocess.Popen()` and do the surrounding plumbing yourself; but this emphatically is not one of those scenarios. You should stay far away from `Popen()` if you can, especially if your understanding of subprocesses is not very sophisticated.

Comment: I cooked this up to address all of your questions, but really, please just accept the duplicate ... and going forward, ask a single, well-defined question per question, please.